# How to make a specific version of PHP works with Xampp on Mac

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, xampp, imagick

Hi guys I'm not a developer so I hope to be clear.

I'm building a website on Wordpress in localhost. So one way to do it is downloading XAMPP (for MAC) which comes with PHP 8.2.4 version.

But I have to install (`brew install php`) a separated version of PHP (8.3 newest) because my command line didn't get php commands work:

```
php -v
-bash: php: command not found
```

According to what I've seen on internet, "you need to install php".

The reason I am doing this is because I need modules (imagick and intl) to make some features work. The problem is that I've got **TWO PHP** versions installed and the modules that I pull are happening for the newest version and not the one it should (Php XAMPP).

How can I make this work?

Comment: Follow the documentation (installation instructions). The installation instructions that came with your download of XAMPP or their website.

Comment: So what are you exactly trying to do? Install both versions of PHP? Difficulty installing PHP? or something else?

Comment: @GetSet the documentation doesn't talk about this specific question. Even on internet is hard to find a clear solution.

Comment: @FreeKrishna I'm trying to use the PHP that comes with XAMPP to download the modules (PHP native modules) that make wordpress features work (like the use of webp images). As I need to use the Terminal for this, with the downloaded Php (8.3, the version that DOESN'T come with XAMPP but I had to download in order to use php commands in terminal) I can do it. But it doesn't work since my localhost (for wordpress) is linked to the php version comes with Xampp. Normally the solution is changing the PATH but even like this it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you use php 8.3 since its still early for use especially with wordpress where most of the plugins . themes are still 7.4/8.0 even 8.1 is risky to be used if you dont know your stuff. As for the terminal i dont see the logic why would require 8.3 to be used in order to use commands.

Comment: @Snuffy Concerning the version 8, I didn't even know about that so I'll keep in mind and downgrade php. About why using php 8.3 is because I wanted to use terminal with php commands in order to get those modules I talked about (with brew command I can't the modules). But terminal do nothing ("command not found" messages) and looking on internet (ChatGPT, Bard...) told me that it is because I don't have php installed so the recommendation was to install it. Suggestions? thank you.